# Error starting application. Module ... not found

Tags: blackberry

I am developing an application for OS 5.0 and above. I am receiving an error when running it on OS 4.6 and I can't enter the application.
What I wanna do is make a try catch to get the error and start the application on OS 4.6 even if a module is not found. For example I want to launch a Main Screen where I want to notify the user to download the new OS version in order to use the application.

Any hint about this topic? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option would be to write a starter application than will run on pre-5.0 OSes that checks the current OS level and launches your application if the OS is OK, or displays your request that they upgrade.

The best solution though is to inform your user base what device/OS combinations you support. If you are doing the installation OTA is is quite easy to detect the OS version from the UserAgent string and act accordingly.

Comment: Hey Richard, I made a seperate project that will check the version of an application and if it is the case, it will launche another project attached as a library in the same package. But I am getting the same error. What did you mean by a starter application? and if so how can I link the application with the starter application? I did that by marking the app as a library but this didn't work

Comment: Did you compile your launcher for a pre-5.0 OS? I'm surprised you are pursuing the non-optimal solution. Do you have a good reason for doing this? A pre-5.0 OS will never run code compiled for a later OS so, as I said in my answer, the best option is to detect the situation prior to installation and just don't get yourself in that situation. RIM provides the tools to do this, trying to go against the current is likely to be more trouble than it is worth.

Comment: Well I am obliged to do that. My situation is the following:

Comment: I want to integrate the BB messenger through my application. But this integration will not work unless you have blackberry messenger 6.0 because I am using classes for this version. I dont care what the version of the cellphone is. All I care about is the version of BBM. So I want to run an application which will check the version of the blackberry messenger and than if it is 6.0 I run the application and if not I prompt the user to download the BBM version 6.0. How to do that with a workaround?

Comment: If you had asked that as your question this would have been so much easier. The BBM development SDK ships with sample code that checks the version of BBM to ensure it is compatable with the SDK. I suggest you look at that.

Answer (score 2):

Because of your `import` statements you won't be able to do that. You'll need to create a separate version for pre-5.0 OSes.